# Dictionary to count table

Tags: python, dictionary

I have generated a dictionary right now that looks like:

```
{'G1':['PF101','PF201','PF204','PF101'],'G2':['PF101','PF202'],'G3':
['PF202','PF204','PF305'],'G4':['PF101','PF305','PF305','PF201']}
```

I want to use it to create a tab delimited count table that looks like:

```
      PF101  PF201  PF204  PF202  PF305
G1      2      1       1      0     0
G2      1      0       0      1     0
G3      0      0       0      1     1
G4      1      1       0      0     2
```

I can't seem to find an efficient way to do this, so any advice would be extremely helpful.  (for reference the actual dictionary has ~2,000 keys)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Well, I had no idea this was a general python question (and not
>   pandas)... well, what do you know, pandas fits in perfectly here!
>
> If you don't have it, please install it. It's *meant* for stuff like
>   this.
>
> ```
> pip install pandas
> ```

**Option 1a**
You can build a dataframe column wise, and call `melt` on the result. Finally, use `pd.crosstab` to compute counts.

```
import pandas as pd

v = pd.concat([pd.Series(v, name=k) for k, v in d.items()], 1).melt()
pd.crosstab(v.variable, v.value)


value     PF101  PF201  PF202  PF204  PF305
variable                                   
G1            2      1      0      1      0
G2            1      0      1      0      0
G3            0      0      1      1      1
G4            1      1      0      0      2
```

Here, `d` is your input dictionary.

**Option 1b**
Alternatively, use `pd.DataFrame.from_dict` to load in your data; the rest of the code is the same, with a small change to the `melt` and `crosstab` syntax from the point of which column names are specified.

```
v = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').reset_index().melt('index')
pd.crosstab(v['index'], v.value)

value  PF101  PF201  PF202  PF204  PF305
index                                   
G1         2      1      0      1      0
G2         1      0      1      0      0
G3         0      0      1      1      1
G4         1      1      0      0      2
```

---

**Option 2**
Another option with `stack` + `str.get_dummies`:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')\
  .stack()\
  .str.get_dummies()\
  .sum(level=0)\
  .sort_index()

    PF101  PF201  PF202  PF204  PF305
G1      2      1      0      1      0
G2      1      0      1      0      0
G3      0      0      1      1      1
G4      1      1      0      0      2
```

A similar solution with `pd.get_dummies` although I'd wager `str.get_dummies` is slightly faster.

```
v = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')\
      .stack()\
      .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)

pd.get_dummies(v).sum(level=0)

    PF101  PF201  PF202  PF204  PF305
G2      1      0      1      0      0
G3      0      0      1      1      1
G1      2      1      0      1      0
G4      1      1      0      0      2
```

---

**Option 3**
`get_dummies` + `dot`. This is something I learned from piRSquared.

```
v = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').stack()
pd.get_dummies(v.index.get_level_values(0)).T.dot(pd.get_dummies(v.values))

    PF101  PF201  PF202  PF204  PF305
G1      2      1      0      1      0
G2      1      0      1      0      0
G3      0      0      1      1      1
G4      1      1      0      0      2
```

*Details*
What it does is create OHEs from, one, the index, and two, the values.

```
pd.get_dummies(v.index.get_level_values(0))

    G1  G2  G3  G4
0    0   1   0   0
1    0   1   0   0
2    0   0   1   0
3    0   0   1   0
4    0   0   1   0
5    1   0   0   0
6    1   0   0   0
7    1   0   0   0
8    1   0   0   0
9    0   0   0   1
10   0   0   0   1
11   0   0   0   1
12   0   0   0   1
```

And,

```
pd.get_dummies(v.values)

    PF101  PF201  PF202  PF204  PF305
0       1      0      0      0      0
1       0      0      1      0      0
2       0      0      1      0      0
3       0      0      0      1      0
4       0      0      0      0      1
5       1      0      0      0      0
6       0      1      0      0      0
7       0      0      0      1      0
8       1      0      0      0      0
9       1      0      0      0      0
10      0      0      0      0      1
11      0      0      0      0      1
12      0      1      0      0      0
```

Finally, find the dot product of these two tensors, and the result is a cross tabulation.

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly, I had no idea pandas could do all that.

Comment: @eric Wait... this _wasn't_ a pandas question? xD Well, now you know you can use pandas here, so you're welcome :)

Comment: @eric Well, there are more than just these 3. For example, you can also use pivot or pivot_table. But for your purposes, these 3 options are sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

While `pandas` is the optimal solution for this problem, you can also create a class to represent your data:

```
class Table:
   def __init__(self, table):
      self.table = table
      self.headers = sorted(set([i for b in self.table.values() for i in b]), key=lambda x:int(x[2:]))
      self.full_table = {a:[(i, b.count(i)) for i in self.headers] for a, b in self.table.items()}
   @property
   def structure(self):
      return self.full_table
   def __repr__(self):
       return '\t'+'\t'.join(self.headers)+'\n'+'\n'.join("{}\t{}".format(a, '\t'.join(map(lambda x:str(x[-1]), b))) for a, b in sorted(self.full_table.items(), key=lambda x:x[0]))

>>>Table(d)

        PF101   PF201   PF202   PF204   PF305
  G1    2       1       0       1       0
  G2    1       0       1       0       0
  G3    0       0       1       1       1
  G4    1       1       0       0       2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way of doing this with pure python:

```
from collections import Counter

d = {'G1':['PF101','PF201','PF204','PF101'],'G2':['PF101','PF202'],
     'G3': ['PF202','PF204','PF305'],'G4':['PF101','PF305','PF305','PF201']}

columns = ['PF101','PF201','PF202', 'PF204', 'PF305']

table = ['\t' + '\t'.join(columns) + '\n']

for key, value in sorted(d.items()):
    temp = [key]
    counts = Counter(value)

    for col in columns:
        if col not in counts:
            counts[col] = 0

    temp.extend([str(v) for _, v in sorted(counts.items())])

    table.append('\t\t'.join(temp) + '\n')

print(''.join(table))
```

Which Outputs:

```
    PF101   PF201   PF202   PF204   PF305
G1      2       1       0       1       0
G2      1       0       1       0       0
G3      0       0       1       1       1
G4      1       1       0       0       2
```